# Conversion of string to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have captured a string from a REST get request and have placed it in a variable. The string is:

```
 {"name":"na1mailboxarchive","objectCount":49564710,"dataBytes":36253526882451},{"name":"na1mailboxarchive2","objectCount":17616567,"dataBytes":13409204616615}
```

I am trying to convert it to a dictionary so I can increment through it and capture the bucket name, size and object count. I have tried eval()

```
bucket_dict = eval(bucket_info)
```

but the program errors out with a:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 83, in <module>
    for k,b in bucket_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

When I print the value of bucket_dict I get:

```
({'name': 'na1mailboxarchive', 'objectCount': 49564710, 'dataBytes': 36253526882451}, {'name': 'na1mailboxarchive2', 'objectCount': 17616567, 'dataBytes': 13409204616615})
```

I think the foul up is the () at the beginning and the end of the dictionary. Nothing else I have tried works either.

Comment: did you try `json.loads()` ?

Comment: This string has two dictionaries, not one.

Comment: _**Never** use `eval()` without a very good, very specific reason. It is an **ENORMOUS security vulnerability** to `eval()` untrusted input, even from an API. Attackers can make your computer do **literally anything**: send spam, distribute malware, destroy your operating system, download and distribute illegal material... Valid uses for `eval()` are **extremely rare**._

Comment: In your error it says there are 2 dictionaries inside a tuple. But in question you have written 1 dict. Check the input correctly

Comment: A REST API should return JSON, not some Python specific representation. However, your string is neither proper JSON nor a standard Python representation. You should check the API specification whether the result is as expected.

Comment: @PrashantKumar The input are two dicts, separated by a comma. This is a valid Python literal for a tuple of dicts.

Comment: @Chris This was an answer from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-create-a-dictionary-from-a-string/. It was nothing I had run across before. The data is all in house on an application that does not have external access. Since eval() did not work I will not be using it going forward. I an uncertain if the value of the histrionics in your answer.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen, the three upvotes on my comment don't convince you that this is truly one of the worst things you can do security-wise? Consider what would happen if one were to craft an API response containing the string `os.system()` with any arbitrary command inside the parentheses. You're basically exposing a command shell to the internet. `eval()` should be used only in exceptionally rare cases. What you call "histrionics" are nothing of the sort. I'm trying to make sure my point sinks in (for you and anybody else who may read this later).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
import ast 

string = '{"name":"na1mailboxarchive","objectCount":49564710,"dataBytes":36253526882451},{"name":"na1mailboxarchive2","objectCount":17616567,"dataBytes":13409204616615}'

result = ast.literal_eval(string)
print(result)
```

`result` is returned as a dictionary

Comment: Checkout the error. Error says it has 2 dictionaries in the string. Read the post carefully.

Comment: result[0] is the first dictionary, result[1] is the second dictionary. This can easily be automated using a for loop.

Comment: @NoCopywriteSpectrums the response I get is:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 84, in <module>
    bucket_dict = ast.literal_eval(bucket_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string:['{"name":"na1mailboxarchive","objectCount":49564701,"dataBytes":36253526882325},{"name":"na1mailboxarchive2","objectCount":17616567,"dataBytes":134092046166}']`

Comment: My outcome is ```>>> bucket_info = '{"name":"na1mailboxarchive","objectCount":49564710,"dataBytes":36253526882451},{"name":"na1mailboxarchive2","objectCount":17616567,"dataBytes":13409204616615}'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(bucket_info)
({'name': 'na1mailboxarchive', 'objectCount': 49564710, 'dataBytes': 36253526882451}, {'name': 'na1mailboxarchive2', 'objectCount': 17616567, 'dataBytes': 13409204616615})
>>> ```

Comment: It may be because i'm inputting the string as `'{"name":"na1mailboxarchive","objectCount":49564710,"dataBytes":36253526882451},{"name":"na1mailboxarchive2","objectCount":17616567,"dataBytes":13409204616615}'`

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.

Firstly the json return from the REST API get is badly formatted. I will take that up with the vendor. Secondly I used some iof the infrmation form @PrashantKumar and @MisterMiyagi to sus out the issue I was having. In my original code I had loaded the list with:

```
bucket_info = [acct_string[acct_string_start+11:acct_len-4]]
```

The variable was capturing the leading "[" and trailing "]" as a part of the string. Once I removed them then the list behaved correctly and I now can work with it. Thank you for the information and the trail markers.